# 'rake test' for minitest aborts in the middle

Tags: ruby, rake, minitest

I have a Rakefile to run all my minitest tests under `tests/`:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'

task :test do
  Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
    t.pattern = 'tests/**/*_test.rb'
    t.verbose = true
  end
end

task default: :test
```

I have required `minitest/autorun` in all my test files.

When I run `bundle exec rake`, rake aborts randomly in the middle with `rake aborted`:

```
☁  fuel [master] ⚡ bundle exec rake
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -I"lib" -I"/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0" "/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "tests/**/*_test.rb"
Connecting to test database
Run options: --seed 43993

# Running:

...................F...F.............................................rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib" -I"/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0" "/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "tests/**/*_test.rb" ]
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@fuel-app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@fuel-app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

☁  fuel [master] ⚡ bundle show rake
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2
```

Even with --trace option, there is no useful info about which test is aborting the runner.

Here is the full stack trace when running with `--trace option`:

```
...........................................................F..........................................rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib" -I"/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0" "/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "tests/**/*_test.rb" ]
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:108:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `call'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `sh'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils.rb:96:in `ruby'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:58:in `verbose'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/testtask.rb:100:in `block in define'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@fuel-app/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@fuel-app/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@fuel-app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/leninraj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@fuel-app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => test
```

What could be the reason? How to find which test is aborting the runner?

Comment: What’s the output with `--trace`? It should al least allow you to see where in your code the error is coming from.

Comment: @matt added the full stacktrace with --trace option. that does not give any useful info

Comment: Argh, you’re right. It’s showing the stacktrace in _Rake_, not from inside the ruby test process.

Comment: Does turning on warnings and verbose mode for Ruby help: `t.ruby_opts << '-w'; t.ruby_opts << '-v'`?

Comment: You could also try debug (`t.ruby_opts << '-d'`), but that will probably give too much output to be useful. It might give a hint as to where to look though.

Comment: @matt thanks. still nothing useful with all three options enabled (w, v, d). rake aborts randomly. here is the full log - http://pastebin.com/LmSUNCEJ

Comment: also checked for killed processes in dmesg. nothing there..